# Change the currency symbol placement

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, currency-formatting

I want to know if it's possible to change the default placement of the currency symbol.
For example the default output will be something like that : `$123,00` but I want it to be like that `123,00 $`.

Note that the culture may change with the user settings

```
public CultureInfo CurrencyCulture { get; }

public string FormatCurrency(decimal value)
{
    var decimalPlace = _config.GetValue<int>("Global.CurrencyDecimalPlace");
    return value.ToString($"C{decimalPlace}", CurrencyCulture);
}
```

Inside the CSHTML

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>@item.Product.Name</div>
    </td>
    <td>@CurrencyService.FormatCurrency(item.ProductPrice)</td>
    <td>@item.Quantity</td>
    <td>@CurrencyService.FormatCurrency(item.ProductPrice * item.Quantity))</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The little bit of information that you are missing is the property [CurrencyPositivePattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern?view=net-5.0) and its more complex counterpart [CurrencyNegativePattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern?view=net-5.0#System_Globalization_NumberFormatInfo_CurrencyNegativePattern)

In the remarks section you could find this table

```
Value   Associated pattern
0       $n
1       n$
2       $ n
3       n $
```

So your code could be written as

```
public string FormatCurrency(decimal value)
{
    CurrencyCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = 3;
    var decimalPlace = _config.GetValue<int>("Global.CurrencyDecimalPlace");
    return value.ToString($"C{decimalPlace}", CurrencyCulture);
}
```